# Django Rest Framework - Column 'brith_date' cannot be null (when it isn't)

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the following error when posting to my api to create a user:

[image: postman integrity error]

I'm using the following function:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        print(validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        validated_data.user_id = user.id
        print(validated_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return profile
```

My user is created perfectly but the error comes up when I'm trying to create the profile.

validated_data contains the following after the user pop:

```
{'phone': '81156598', 'birth_date': datetime.date(2017, 6, 29)}
```

I'm adding afterwards the user_id from the user that was created and passing that in my `Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)` but I get the birth_date cannot be null error. Do I need to get all my date formats from a post and then send it back to validated_data? There should be another way shouldn't it?

Thank you

**EDIT**:

This is the profile model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.user.username)
```

Comment: if your birth_date is datetime field,try `2017-06-29 00:00`

Comment: can you post your Profile Model?

Comment: @Ykh its a DateField, AhmedHosny Updated with the model

Comment: try `birth_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)`

Comment: `validated_data.user_id = user.id` don't do this. Instead `validated_data.user_id = request.user.id` since your validated data may maliciously  contain other user id. So better to save it as the current user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is here:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

you use signal to create profile once user is created,when you create profile instance,you doesn't pass var birth_day(which is null=False),then you will get error when you create a user not when you create profile.set `birth_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)` or set `birth_day` to `datetime.now()` when you create profile in `create_user_profile`.
and your may change your create in profile,when you create user,`create_user_profile` will create a profile,you need to check user has profile or not before you create it manual.

Comment: you are right, let me try it in a while and get back to see if that fixed it!

Comment: Thanks that worked, I simply removed those two functions and made it so my serializer handles making sure they both get created, one last thing though... my `password` field pops up empty, do I have to do something special there? Thank you

Comment: password can't be set directly, you need use `user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)`,it's `create_user` not `create`

Comment: thanks, that hashes and puts up the password but when checking the user from my admin site it shows `No password set.` for that user, checking the database from my workbench shows there is a password but I can't log in with that new user even if its set as superuser, staff, active or whatever

Comment: raw password need use method make_password(raw_password) to hashesd password,or just use user.set_password(raw_password),if you save your raw_password directly to db,you can't login with raw password.